# SFTP ChannelSftp.put stop it's execution process but successfully being uploaded or copy the source file

Tags: java, sftp, dropwizard, jsch, microservices

details:

in my API i have struggle on debugging why is that the ChannelSftp.put method hangs up or stop it's execution process but when checking it's output it is successfully being uploaded.

here's my code snippet:

MyService.class

```
@Inject
MyConfiguration conf;

public String copyAndMove( String fileName ){
    try{
        MyServer origin = conf.getOriginServer().setFileName( fileName );
        MyServer destination = conf.getDestinationServer().setFileName( fileName );

        SFTPServer originSftpServer = new SFTPServer( origin ).build();
        SFTPServer destinationSftpServer = new SFTPServer( destination ).build();

        // originSftpServer.copyTo(destinationSftpServer);
        originSftpServer.copyTo(originSftpServer);

        return "Successfully copied file.";
        }catch( Exception ex ){
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
```

SFTPServer.class

```
public class SFTPServer {

    private MyServer server;
    private static SFTPServer instance;

    private Session session = null;
    private Channel channel = null;
    private ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

    // getters and setters

    public SFTPServer(){}

    public SFTPServer(MyServer server) throws  Exception{
        if(CommonUtil.isNull( server )){
            throw new Exception("MyServer cannot be null!");
        }

        this.server = server;
    }

    public SFTPServer build(){
        try{
            this.session = SFTPUtil.constructSession(getServer());
            this.channel = SFTPUtil.constructChannel(getSession());
            this.channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

            return this;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    public SFTPServer copyTo( SFTPServer destination ) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try{
            ChannelSftp channel = destination.getChannelSftp();
            String originSourceFile = String.format("%s/%s", getServer().getSourceFilePath(), getServer().getFileName());
            String destinationProcessedFile = String.format("%s/%s", destination.getServer().getProcessedFilePath(), destination.getServer().getFileName());

            is = getChannelSftp().get(originSourceFile);
            channel.put(is, destinationProcessedFile, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);

            return this;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }finally{
            CommonUtil.closeQuitely(is); // close input stream
            destination.destroy(); // disconnect session, channel, channelSftp
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is this. it's seems that it cannot proceed until the program done for it's execution. when i debug on it it stop and it's execution for this code: **channel.put(is, destinationProcessedFile, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);** but on the sftp server it is successfully being copied from source to destination file path. please help me with this problem because it cannot return the **Successfully copied file.** on the service part. thanx.

Comment: Do you mean that the `channel.put` never exits OR that is exits only after the upload finishes?

Comment: @Martin Prikryl no, i mean ChannelSftp the method put( InputStream is, String dst, int mode); never exits after successfully being uploaded or being executed. don't know what's the problem for that? please help :D

Comment: What is the `originSourceFile`? Is it a normal file or some device?

Comment: these directories are same physical Server. originSourceFile ==> local/source/test1.txt
destinationProcessedFile  ==> local/processed/test1.txt

Comment: What happens if you loop reading `is` (instead of passing it to `channel.put`) until you get `-1`?

Answer (score 0):

As I've not able figure this one out using input streams, absolute vs relative pathings, here is an alternative:

Instead of using put, use rename

```
    try
    {
        channelSftp.cd(destinationDirectory);
        channelSftp.rename(pathToFile1, pathToFile2);
        channelSftp.cd(currentDirectory);
    } catch (SftpException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Basically it renames a file from one directory to another. Move to the destination directory, use rename to create that file there, and change back to the directory you were in.

(I would've rather used the .put method, but ran into the same issue.)

Comment: How can you use `rename` instead of `put`? Makes no sense.

Comment: `put` uploads a local file (or local data) to the server. `rename` renames existing remote file to another (remote) name/folder. They serve completely different purposes. If your question is about problems with `put` and you suggest using `rename` in the answer, it about the same as if someone asked about fixing a car, and you suggested to use a go swimming.

Comment: Sorry, I just do not know how else to phrase it for you to understand it. Please read my previous comment once again *very slowly and carefully*.