# ChannelSftp.put method gets stuck when using input stream from ChannelSftp.get

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

My scenario is: 
I'm using **Jsch** lib(v - 0.1.54), to work with **SFTP**
Everything works fines except when I try to use **sftpChannel.put()** method, it uploads the file but the process get stuck

Code:

```
public static void moveFiles() {
    //some code
     try {
           InputStream fis =  sftpChannel.get(currentDirectory+"/"+fileName);

           sftpChannel.put(fis, fileName,  ChannelSftp.RESUME);//"freezes here, no exception is thrown

           fis.close();
         } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
    //some other code
}
```

I've checked if there's already any other issue like that one I'm facing but there's is no solution to it(apparently)

[Same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026454/sftp-channelsftp-put-stop-its-execution-process-but-successfully-being-uploaded)

Thanks in advance o/

Comment: Did you try to debug the `put` method to see where it gets stuck?

Answer (score 4):

I figure it out the solution after digging further the matter 
I need one ChannelSftp to get the file and another one ChannelSftp to use put

```
  public static void moveFiles() {
      //some code
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = getChannel();
    ChannelSftp sftpChannelDownload = getChannel();
     try {
        InputStream fis = sftpChannelDownload.get(currentDirectory+"/"+fileName);
        sftpChannel.put(fis, fileName);
    }  catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //more code
  }
```